# How to convert numpy.ndarray to scipy.sparse.coo_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pytorch, sparse-matrix

The error I'm getting is:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().`

I saw some questions about it `.any()` or `.all()`, but didn't solve my problem. I built a sparse block diagonal matrix, by using `scipy.linalg.block_diag`, as I need to input `torch.sparse` tensor to my model. And (as far as I know) the only way for creating `torch.sparse` tensor is using `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`. However, after building the block diagonal matrix, it automatically becomes `numpy.ndarray`, and torch.sparse doesn't take this input. I've tried many things, but couldn't handle. (I've tried many pytorch sparse tensor builder library, or code also, but didn't work.)

I have tried to convert back to `scipy`, and it worked for this toy matrix:

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

a = [2]
b = [3,4]
x = block_diag(a,b)
print(x)
print(type(x))
s = sp.coo_matrix(x, dtype = sp.coo_matrix)
print(s)
print(type(s))
```

Output:

```
 [[2 0 0]
 [0 3 4]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
  (0, 0)    2
  (1, 1)    3
  (1, 2)    4
<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>
```

But when I try with my real matrix, it gives me "Boolean" Value Error.

```
sparse = sp.coo_matrix(top5_block.any(), dtype = sp.coo_matrix)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I have tried `.all()` and `.any()` (if i did correctly), both of them gives the same error. If I don't use them, still gives the same error. For sparse tensor I need sparse block diagonal matrix(with hybrid sparse tensor I also tried, but my model didn't work.), but it is backfiring me.
My sparse block diagonal matrix has a size of 50x50, and each of those 50 has different size of another square matrix(as it is block diagonal).

```
[[<183x183 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 8043 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
  0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0
  <169x169 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4081 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
  0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0
  <188x188 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5996 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
  ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ...
  <157x157 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1513 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
  0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0
  <121x121 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1373 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
  0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0
  <262x262 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5890 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]]
(50, 50)
```

Any help to convert this block diagonal matrix back to `scipy.sparse` would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
This is how I obtained sparse diagonal matrix(Or at least I thought):

```
def build_block_diag(matrice_list): 
    return block_diag(*matrice_list)

top5_block = build_block_diag(mat_list)
```

Comment: `coo_matrix` works with a 2d numeric array. Skip that `dtype` parameter. That `block_diag` cannot assemble sparse matrices.  To join those use a `sparse` function.

Comment: I've tried without dtype also, but didn't work. @hpaulj

Comment: I didn't say that the dtype specification was the problem.  What are the inputs to `block_diag`?

Comment: A list of adjacency matrices. What I was trying to do building a big graph with many disconnected sub-graphs.

Comment: Anyways, that array created by `block_diag` is object dtype (50,50) shape.  Each sparse matrix has been wrapped in a single item numpy array.  In other words, `block_diag` does not treat the matrices as anything special.  Look at its code to see what it is actually doing (it's simple Python).

Comment: `block_diag([m.A for m in matrice_list])` might do what you want.  Try it on a small list first.

Comment: Hi, your comments helped me to understand my mistake, thanks a lot. It was because of the fact that at the first place when I built the adjacency matrices, their type was ```numpy.array```, I changed it to ```numpy.matrix```, and when I returned back to the same place (converting ```numpy.ndarray``` to ```scipy.sparse```) this time I didn't get any error. It successfully did it. If you can write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. It helped me to understand my mistake anyway. @hpaulj